# Why arent my Student strings printing out?

Tags: java

I have three small java classes, and I am trying to read some data in from a file and print it out. Here are my codes, and they are pretty short.

Student.java

```
package students;

import java.text.*;

public class Student{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private double gpa;

    public Student(String name, int age, double gpa){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String gpa_string = new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(gpa);
        return name + " " + Integer.toString(age) + " " + gpa_string + "\n";
    }
}
```

Students.java

```
package students;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Students {
    public static final int MAX = 100;
    private Student students[];
    private int count;

    public void readFile(String path) throws IOException{
        students = new Student[MAX];
        Scanner x = new Scanner(new File(path));
        count = 0;
        while (x.hasNextLine() && count < MAX){
            String name = x.nextLine();
            if("".equals(name)){
                System.out.println("Breaking out of loop");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(name);
            int age = x.nextInt();
            System.out.println(age);
            double gpa = x.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(gpa);
            students[count] = new Student(name, age, gpa);
            count += 1;
            System.out.println(count)
        }
        x.close();
    }

    public String toString(){
        String result = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            result += students[i].toString();
        return result;
    }
```

Driver.java

```
package students;

import java.io.*;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Students students = new Students();
        students.readFile("Students.txt");
        System.out.print(students.toString());
    }
}
```

and this is what Students.txt looks like:

```
Name0
22
1.2
Name1
22
2.71
Name2
19
3.51
```

I'm expecting to see this:
    Name0 22 1.2
    Name1 22 2.71
    Name2 19 3.51

But instead I get no output at all. I am not sure what is going on. Is the file not being found? I am coming from python, and it seems like a `try: ... except: pass` sort of thing deal is going on with the `throws IOException` stuff.

I am using Eclipse, and I have Students.txt in the src folder, the bin folder, and at the top of the workspace because I don't know where it needs to go.

**EDIT:**

After changing the conditions of the while loop and adding a bunch of print statements, I got it to read a single student in. The output now is:
    Name0
    22
    1.2
    1
    Breaking out of loop
    Name0 22 1.20

I don't understand why it is stopping after 1 loop.

Comment: Did you debug your code? I mean, did you try to even print out some data about reading the file? Like every loop print out a 'loop' message or something.

Comment: @newboyhun Good Idea! :3 will update my question

Comment: @Broseph re: your update, see my updated answer

Answer (score 4):

The following condition:

```
 x.hasNextLine() &&x.hasNextInt() && x.hasNextDouble() && count < MAX
```

will always evaluate to `false`. How can `x` have next `Int` and `Double` simultaneosly? Think about the format of input file. Maybe you can make it tab-delimited (or any other delimiter), with assumption one line - one Student? In such a case it's much easier to implement reading method with only one condition inside `if x.hasNextLine`

Answer (score 2):

```
while (x.hasNextLine() &&x.hasNextInt() && x.hasNextDouble() && count < MAX)
```

Think about this conditional...

`hasNextInt( )` and `hasNextDouble( )` are mutually exclusive, so it will always return false.

Conceptually, understand that `x.hasNexInt()` doesn't mean "`x` has another int somewhere" , it means that the *next* element in `x`is an int.

Also, unrelated but: Generally, when you find yourself with a conditional statement like this (with more than one `&&`, as a rule of thumb), you should ask yourself if you really can simplify that conditional by breaking it into multiple statements.

***EDIT:*** (in response to your update) Try running it without the `if("".equals(name))` clause. It's not immediately apparent to me why it's being triggered before it's expected to, but your output indicates that it is, and in any case this clause seems redundant: Your `hasNextLine( )` conditional at the top already provides a mechanism for exiting the loop at the end of the dataset. There are situations where a secondary check like this is necessary, but ask yourself if you're in one.

Comment: nextInt and nextFloat don't consume the trailing newlines. Calling nextLine after nextFloat gave the empty string.